# Only if at the middle of a sentence vs only if at the start of a sentence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Is it correct to say "A only if B" and "Only if B, then A"?
For example,

Only if in middle of sentence: **We’ll win the ICG cup only if we have enough players.**

Only if at start of sentence: **Only if we have enough players, will we then win the ICG cup.**

Comment: Both are correct, though the comma in the second one should be omitted.

Comment: Is it a question about English grammar or about the logical content of a statement?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, and they are equivalent to each other. Also, in a mathematical context, both clearly mean $A\implies B$. People who haven't learned enough mathematics may, however, interpret "only if" as $\iff$. When talking to non-mathematicians, I'd probably rephrase this, perhaps as "We won't win the ICG cup unless we have enough players."

Comment: It you are not a native English speaker, then I would avoid using "only if'" except in the context of "if and only if" which forces us to take in what you mean. Brian is right that the comma in the second example is technically wrong, but you can put a comma in the first example (after "only") and completely change the meaning. To this English speaker, the word "only" in "foo only if bar" doesn't carry much force: say "if bar then foo" if that is what you mean. Even better talk about "necessary conditions" or "sufficient conditions" to force your readers to think precisely.

Comment: PS: I didn't mean to sound patronising about the use of "only if" by non-English speakers: in fact, what I meant was that we English speakers are much less precise and use the word "only" and the phrases "if only" and "only if" in strange colloquial ways.